# Is it possible to move a SharePoint 2010 folder from one document library to another with a workflow?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, folder

I would have thought an overwhelming yes but it does not seem so...

I know you can do it by opening in explorer but I need to do it with a workflow preferably with SharePoint designer but if it can only be through code I'll live.

If not, are there any workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Probably you can try enhancing `CopyItemExtended` custom activity

http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy%20List%20Item%20Extended%20Activity&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Well that's no good :(
Thanks anyway!